# Does anyone know of a simple overview/tutorial for APNS?

Tags: perl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cpan

I want to send notifications to a desktop Mac (and maybe eventually my iPhone) from a shell script (bash, perl, something like that).

I'm aware that APNS is what I want, but Apple does a really poor job of explaining what that is. For the iPhone at least, it seems that I'd have to install an app (of my own creation), plus set up some configuration of certificates, and then send notifications through their service. Please correct me if that is essentially wrong.

Is the same required for OSX notifications? Can I send notifications locally (to the same machine) without all the rigamarole?

Perl seems to have a CPAN module that might make things slightly easier, but I've yet to find examples or tutorials how to use it.

I need help getting started, and my Google searches aren't turning up anything that makes much sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications are only available on iOS. Push Notifications are available on both iOS and OSX from 10.7 (Lion).

I agree that the configuration of certificates is quite annoying, but the [Local and Push Notifications Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW2) Apple provide is good enough if that is your solution of choice.

However, if you only need something local on OSX, you can probably run some service in the background that would trigger the required behavior at the required time. I'm not familier with OSX, so I can't be more specific. 
I assume that the reason Local Notifications exist only for iOS is that you can't run applications in the background on iOS. Push Notifications are available for both since they are triggered by a remote server.